# Deploying django app to heroku - can't find file

Tags: django, heroku

I have a problem running my django app on heroku. It has been deployed successfully but it has some problems finding various files.

in *news.py*

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
url_path = BASE_DIR + '/marketdata/news/'
```

which works locally but when I deploy it on heroku it says it can't find the file

> Exception Value:   [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/app/artemis/static/marketdata/news/bloomberg_news.csv' Exception
>   Location: /app/artemis/static/marketdata/news.py in save_to_csv, line
>   16

and this is my project structure

[image]

Any idea how this would be solved? Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
if i check my project structure on heroku the *news* folder is not there at all. Does this have to do with the fact that it only has .csv files in it?

Comment: Is that folder (and its contents) included in your git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue I was having:

- I didn't run `python manage.py collectstatic` before committing to heroku
- The other problem was with my *procfile*. Changing it to: `web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
   solved my issue

Comment: Weird, i found this info in the docs for deploying a python app to django I posted.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already done this, give this a read and follow the steps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

You probably have, but posting for reference just in case. So, those files are located within your static area. Heroku is a little interesting when it comes to static files. Another question I answered is most likely related to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373830/4954874.

The problem you are having is it can't find the file, because it is located in your static directory which in turn is found by using `/static/` which allows heroku to find it. I believe if you do something like this `/static/marketdata/news/` it should work.